# How do I run my CI steps in a specific folder in github action

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I have a `golang` repo with a `react` client. I want to setup up CI using github actions for my client. The React client is inside the `client` folder in the workspace.
I have written the following workflow

```
name : Node.js CI

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  build:
    name: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2 
      with:
        path: client
    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 12.x

    - run: yarn install

    - run: yarn build
```

But on committing it shows the following error

```
 Run yarn build1s
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
Run yarn build
yarn run v1.21.1
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/home/runner/work/evential/evential"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1
```

The snippet

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2 
      with:
        path: client
```

doesn't make the steps following run inside the `client` folder.

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `working-directory` keyword in a `run` step. See the documentation [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun).

```
    - run: yarn install
      working-directory: client

    - run: yarn build
      working-directory: client
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as this won' t fix the problem that ```uses``` wont run with the working-directory and will still fail.

Comment: Actions referenced by `uses` need to support a `path` input. If they don't then there is nothing really that you can do. You should ask the action author to support it.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c586ad6448df17a1034a99f451a38ff7

working-directory: '../../frontend/' is not working can you please look the structure

Comment: This does not solve the question that was asked

Comment: This resolve my issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your repository structure looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── client
│   └── ... # your source files
└── workflows
    └── example-ci.yml
```

You can also set the default working directory for multiple steps using:

```yaml
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: client # The working directory path
```

This way you don't need to specify it for each steps.
You can also adjust the scope depending on where you put the above snippet, either for:

- All steps of all jobs: put it at the *base* of your workflow.
- All steps of one job: put it *within the job* in the jobs attribute of your workflow so it applies to the steps of that job.