# How to specify node's path in Github action?

Tags: npm, github-actions

I'm trying to use Github's node.js workflow for automating test on my repository. However, I'm having difficulties because node is set up in a child directory instead of the root of my repository. I have been looking for a way to specify the directory in which to run the npm commands but have not found any answer.

Here is the workflow code:

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x, 14.x, 16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with: 
        path: backend_app
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: cd backend_app
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

Here is the error generated by the action run :

```
    Run npm ci
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/directory_name/directory_name/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/directory_name/directory_name/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-06-16T03_36_41_777Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

Comment: Please review the answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this has been answered already.

[How do I run my CI steps in a specific folder in github action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145596/how-do-i-run-my-ci-steps-in-a-specific-folder-in-github-action)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Please specify the "Working-Directory". Please refer to my .yml file.

1. **working-directory: ./Projects/books-store-mean/webapi**

Work flow file for reference: [https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/actions/workflows/booksstore-nodeexpressmongo.yml](https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/actions/runs/941714053/workflow)

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code, and run tests across different versions of the node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: ./Projects/books-store-mean/webapi
    - run: npm run build --if-present
      working-directory: ./Projects/books-store-mean/webapi
    - run: npm test
      working-directory: ./Projects/books-store-mean/webapi
```

Comment: For those who need to specify the path to the lockfile for the `setup-node@v2` step, you can add an additional line under `with`, like so: `cache-dependency-path: ./some/path/package-lock.json`

Comment: @derekbaker783 it's astonishing how hard it was to find this answer. Thanks!