# How to specifiy path for actions/setup-node in Github

Tags: node.js, yaml, github-actions

Note: I have already seen these two:

[How do I run my CI steps in a specific folder in github action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145596/how-do-i-run-my-ci-steps-in-a-specific-folder-in-github-action) 
[How to specify node's path in Github action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996191/how-to-specify-nodes-path-in-github-action?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But I still cant get it to work, thats why I am asking how I am able to set the working directory for a `uses` command. My yaml currently looks as follows:

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, Create-.yml-file ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, Create-.yml-file ]

jobs:
  javatest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '16'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Cache Maven packages
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.m2
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
        restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: |
          mvn -f ./backend/pom.xml -B test
          #mvn -f ./notification/pom.xml -B test

    - name: Generate JaCoCo Badge
      uses: cicirello/jacoco-badge-generator@v2
      with:
        generate-branches-badge: true
        on-missing-report: quiet
        jacoco-csv-file: >
          -backend/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv

    - name: Log coverage percentage
      run: |
        echo "coverage = ${{ steps.jacoco.outputs.coverage }}"
        echo "branch coverage = ${{ steps.jacoco.outputs.branches }}"

    - name: Commit the badge (if it changed)
      run: |
        if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
          git config --global user.name 'myusername'
          git config --global user.email 'myId@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add -A
          git commit -m "Autogenerated JaCoCo coverage badge"
          git push
        fi

    - name: Upload JaCoCo coverage report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: jacoco-report
        path: target/site/jacoco/
      
  nodejstest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: ./frontend
    - run: npm run build --if-present
      working-directory: ./frontend
    - run: npm test
      working-directory: ./frontend
```

with the error occuring here:

```
 - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
```

And looking like this:

```
Run actions/setup-node@v2
/usr/local/bin/npm config get cache
/home/runner/.npm
Error: Dependencies lock file is not found in /home/runner/work/path/to/main/directory. Supported file patterns: package-lock.json,yarn.lock
```

My package-lock ist located in the .../path/to/main/directory/frontend so it is obvious that it can not be found but according to the other two solutions this snippet should work shouldn't it? I also already tried combining the last three run statements into as well as move the working-directory setting to different places. All with varying amounts of failure

Comment: [_"At the moment, only lock files in the project root are supported"_](https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-packages-dependencies)

Comment: @jonrsharpe using cache-dependency-path its possible

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The support for custom path (relative to repository root) was added in version 2.4:
https://github.com/actions/setup-node/releases/tag/v2.4.0

1. You can try specifying `'**/package-lock.json'` in the
   `cache-dependency-path` (it didn't work for me with other patterns).
2. Also you can try setting the `working directory` (either for all jobs or your `nodejstest` specific job) to point to your `frontend` folder.

```
  nodejstest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: 'frontend' # Here the path to the folder where package-lock.json is located.
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x] # Are you are missing this specification?
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
        cache-dependency-path: '**/package-lock.json' # THIS PATTERN did the trick for me.
```

Comment: "try specifying '**/package-lock.json' in the cache-dependency-path" <== This worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

```
setup_build_environment:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest
defaults:
  run:
    shell: bash
strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [14.x]
    # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

steps:


- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v2
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'yarn'
    cache-dependency-path: ./node-app/yarn.lock

- name: run npm commands
  working-directory: node-app
  run: | 
    yarn && CI=true
    # yarn build --if-present
    # yarn test
    node test.js
```

Reference : https://github.com/actions/setup-node#caching-packages-dependencies

> The action defaults to search for the dependency file (package-lock.json or yarn.lock) in the repository root, and uses its hash as a part of the cache key. Use cache-dependency-path for cases when multiple dependency files are used, or they are located in different subdirectories.

I have used yarn, and the node app resides in /node-app directory, so in **cache-dependency-path** I use the lock file from yarn. And using **working-directory** for running yarn commands in node-app directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can break down Node setup and cache into two steps like below

```
  nodejstest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name : Cache
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: "frontend/node_modules"
        key: node-modules-${{ hashFiles('frontend/package.json') }}
    - run: npm ci
      working-directory: ./frontend
    - run: npm run build --if-present
      working-directory: ./frontend
    - run: npm test
      working-directory: ./frontend
```